# WPF: menu with content area , menu item click?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to have a `Dictionary<string , SomeView>` so that i display the keys in the menu and when someone clicks the menuitem , the corrosponding `SomeView` is injected into a `ContentControl`

I have:

```
<Menu Name="menu"/>
<ContentControl Name="content"/>
```

and:

```
public partial class TestWindow : Window
{
    Dictionary<string, TextBlock> menuItems = new Dictionary<string,TextBlock>();

    public TestWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        menuItems.Add("sign-in", new TextBlock(){Text="sign in"});
        menuItems.Add("register", new TextBlock(){Text="sign up"});

        menu.ItemsSource = menuItems.Keys;
    }
}
```

how do I get the menu item click event and get the corrosponding string to that menu item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> IF YOU ARE USING MVVM, THIS IS NOT THE RIGHT WAY TO DO THINGS

Xaml:

```
<Menu >
        <Menu.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="ContextMenuClick" />
            </Style>
        </Menu.Resources>
            <MenuItem Header="_File" Name="File">
                <MenuItem Name="Hello" Header="_Hello"/>
                <MenuItem Name="Never" Header="_Never"/>
                <MenuItem Name="Do" Header="_Do "/>
                <MenuItem Name="This" Header="_This"/>
            </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
```

C#:

```
private void ContextMenuClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("MyContent:{0}", ((MenuItem) sender).Name));
    }
```